# How to enable vscode show results of plot from server while debug?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I am using Remote Development extension of vscode to debug my code on the remote server. How to set up Remote Development extension to show the figure of intermedia results during debugging? I want to know whether vscode can support this function?

Microsoft has recently published Remote Development extension which enables me to write and debug code in the remote server just like in my own computer.
One way to achieve is to use X11 forward. I tried Xming. However, I can only know to enable it to support terminals like putty. I got stuck on how to enable X server to support terminal of vscode.

I want to show some figures by plot.show() or cv2.imshow() during the debug process just locally debugging.

Comment: Is it working? I'm still facing this issue!!!